# Does the diffeomorphisms of the constant rank theorem maps $p$ and $f(p)$ to the origin?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

This is the proof of the constant rank theorem in Euclidean Space from Loring Tu's manifold text in the appendix:
[image]

[image]

I am trying to figure out why the maps $G$ and $F$ map $p$ and $f(p)$ to the origins respectively because it doesn't seem like they do based on their construction. Of course, I know we can always compose with a translation to fix that, but based on how they are construted in this proof, they in fact do not map $p$ and $f(p)$ to the origins correct?

Comment: OK, I didn't read all that but you are most probably right. They forgot to compose with a translation or maybe did so on purpose so as not to overload the notation. That is not a fundamental issue at all

Comment: yeah i think thats the case. It's not a big problem but I did get stuck for a while trying to figure out what I was missing :)

Comment: Most of the time in such proofs the simplification is made at the very beginning to assume that $p=0$ and $f(p)=0$.